# How to synchronise RDBMS data with HDFS data

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs

I have Oracle database comprising 300 tables and all type of DML operations (insert/Update/delete) are performed on these tables . I have moved move my present data from RDBMS to HDFS using Sqoop . Now I want to synchronise real time data with HDFS data whenever any DML operation is performed. Can I use Kafka for this purpose and will it support update and delete operations.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to an extent. You can [stream databases into Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc), but how you handle updates & deletes landing to HDFS depends on how you get the data out of your source, and your reasons for landing it to HDFS. 
You can use the [HDFS sink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html) to stream from Kafka to HDFS, but this will not update/delete data already present in HDFS. For that you would need some custom processing.

What's the reason for landing the data to HDFS and needing realtime sync with the DB? Perhaps the pattern you're looking for may not be best suited to HDFS (not typically a realtime technology)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for a solution which can be used to update the data in HDFS as per the DML changes done  on the Table. It would be great help if you have suggestions.

Comment: but *why* do you want to update the data in HDFS? What process is it driving? My suggestions are above in my answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rethink your choice with HDFS. For example, [Apache Kudu](https://kudu.apache.org/) might be better suited for your use case. Especially under the consideration, that your main data source is an RDBMS.

Further Informations:

- https://kudu.apache.org/
- https://de.slideshare.net/MichaelPercy3/using-kafka-and-kudu-for-fast-lowlatency-sql-analytics-on-streaming-data